# jQuery .hide() does not work with my array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello and thanks for your help.

I have a php script on my website that returns my last few tweets in form of an unordered list with the posts each being a list item.

```
<div id="latesttweet">
  <ul>
    <li>
      This is a tweet<br />
      <span>3 hours ago.</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      This is another tweet<br />
      <span>4 hours ago.</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to hide some of them dynamically using JavaScript, but for some reason once I collect all the list items in an Array, I can't address them properly anymore. When I alert the length of the Array however, I get the right number. 
jQuery seems to be working alright in general.

```
var activeTweet = 0;
var tweet_ul = document.getElementById('latesttweet');
var tweetArray = tweet_ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

var tweetCount = tweetArray.length;
alert(tweetCount); //returns the right result

tweetArray[1].hide();
```

This way, one should expect that the second list item would have `display` set to `none`, but still both items remain visible.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $(tweetArray[1]).hide();

Comment: remember array starts from `0` so try `$(tweetArray[0]).hide();`

Comment: Why do you use jquery for hiding an element and normal javascript for access to the element?

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski - Note that the question specified hiding the second list item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are not using jQuery

```
$(tweetArray[1]).hide()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your array are DOM objects, not jQuery objects.
Try the following:

```
var activeTweet = 0;
var tweet_ul = $('#latesttweet');
var tweetArray = $('li');

var tweetCount = tweetArray.length;
alert(tweetCount); //returns the right result

tweetArray[1].hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(tweetArray[1]).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tweetArray[1].style.display="none";
```

Comment: There is no jQuery in the question's code, although it was tagged as such.  This is the only answer that doens't introduce jQuery arbitrarily.  +1.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(tweetArray[1]).hide();
```

This should do the job. tweetArray[1] is just an html element and it does not have hide() method defined for it.

Answer (score 0):

`hide()` is part of jQuery. You have to use the `$()` method: `$(tweetArray[1]).hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to wrap `tweetArray[1]` into a jquery object

Try

`$(tweetArray[1]).hide();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var tweets = $( '#latesttweet ul' ).children( 'li' ); 
$( tweets[1] ).hide();
```

http://jsbin.com/usiyex/2/